# How to display alert when multiple check values are different

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Each li tag has a data-push-cate value.
ex)melo, thriller, horror...

When the user clicks on the a.product-compare tag,
The check class is being added to the li tag.

Here are some situations in which you need help.

When the user clicks on a.product-compare,
**If the value of data-push-cate in li is different, we want to display an alert.**

Please give me a hint.

js

```
$(document).on('click', '.product-compare', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  if($(this).closest('li').hasClass('check')){
    //data value compare
    alert("You can only compare products in the same category.");
  }

  $(this).closest('li').addClass('check');
});
```

php

```
..loop
<ul class="product-action-buttons absolute text-right right-0 z-10">
  <li data-push-cate="melo">
    <a href="#;" class="product-compare" title="product-compare">
      <span class="blind">product-compare</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li data-push-cate="thriller">
    <a href="#;" class="product-compare" title="product-compare">
      <span class="blind">product-compare</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li data-push-cate="horror">
    <a href="#;" class="product-compare" title="product-compare">
      <span class="blind">product-compare</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li data-push-cate="melo">
    <a href="#;" class="product-compare" title="product-compare">
      <span class="blind">product-compare</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Teemu Sorry, the content of the question has been changed.

Comment: "_If the value of data-push-cate in li is different_" Different from what? Different from a previously clicked item?

Comment: @Teemu Yes, it is. Sorry for the lack of explanation.

Comment: You've to store a reference to the clicked item into a variable (or at least the value of `data-push-cate`), then you can compare the stored value to the current value you read from the attribute.

Comment: You've to add the explanation for "_different_" in your question too. It's not easy to find from the comments.

Comment: @Teemu Corrected the title and content.

Comment: Hi, did you resolve this issue ?

Comment: @Swati no. I haven't solved it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first check if the `check` class is not there in any `li` tag if yes just add `check` class to `li` where `a` has been clicked. Now , in else part get the `data-attribute` of `check` class using this compare it with the `li` where `a` tag has been clicked if match just add `check` class there else show some error message.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).on('click', '.product-compare', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //check if the `check` class length is 0
  if ($(".product-action-buttons li.check").length == 0) {
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('check'); //no problem just add class
  } else {
    //get check class data attr
    var check_Class = $("li.check:first").data("push-cate");
    console.log(check_Class)
    //check if the li has the same data attr
    if ($(this).closest('li').data('push-cate') == check_Class) {
      $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('check'); //okay fine just add class
    } else {
      //show some message
      alert("You can only compare products in the same category.");
    }
  }

});
```

```css
.check {
  border: 1px solid grey
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="product-action-buttons absolute text-right right-0 z-10">
  <li data-push-cate="melo">
    <a href="#;" class="product-compare" title="product-compare">
      <span class="blind">product-compare</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li data-push-cate="thriller">
    <a href="#;" class="product-compare" title="product-compare">
      <span class="blind">product-compare</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li data-push-cate="horror">
    <a href="#;" class="product-compare" title="product-compare">
      <span class="blind">product-compare</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li data-push-cate="melo">
    <a href="#;" class="product-compare" title="product-compare">
      <span class="blind">product-compare</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the perfect solution, have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

First of all I think there is a typo here, it means (**Unchecked**) I guess.

```js
  if($(this).closest('li').hasClass('check')){
    //data value compare
    alert("You can only compare products in the same category.");
  }
```

But here it is valid if it has been checked. Let's continue fixing this.

```js
  if( ! $(this).closest('li').hasClass('check') ){
    //data value compare
    alert("You can only compare products in the same category.");
  }
```

Has anything of the same value been checked now? Let's add his query.

```js
  if (!$(this).closest('li').hasClass('check')) {
    var value = $(this).closest('li').attr('data-push-cate');

    if (value && $('li[data-push-cate*="' +
        value + '"]').hasClass('check')) {
      alert("You can only compare products in the same category.");
    } else {
      $(this).closest('li').addClass('check');
    }
  }
```

I'll try to create a live snippet about it. Good luck with.

#### Run Code Snippet:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.product-compare', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (!$(this).closest('li').hasClass('check')) {
    var value = $(this).closest('li').attr('data-push-cate');

    if (value && $('li[data-push-cate*="' +
        value + '"]').hasClass('check')) {
      alert("You can only compare products in the same category.");
    } else {
      $(this).closest('li').addClass('check');
    }
  }

});
```

```css
li.check a {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="product-action-buttons absolute text-right right-0 z-10">
  <li data-push-cate="melo">
    <a href="#;" class="product-compare" title="product-compare">
      <span class="blind">product-compare</span> (Click me first)
    </a>
  </li>
  <li data-push-cate="thriller">
    <a href="#;" class="product-compare" title="product-compare">
      <span class="blind">product-compare</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li data-push-cate="horror">
    <a href="#;" class="product-compare" title="product-compare">
      <span class="blind">product-compare</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li data-push-cate="melo">
    <a href="#;" class="product-compare" title="product-compare">
      <span class="blind">product-compare</span> (Click me second)
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you.
But the code seems to work when it is in the same category.
I want to display an alert when a different category value is selected.